# PHP mailer, gmail smtp not sending email from live server

Tags: smtp

I have the following code to send email:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'imap.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'my gmail id';
        $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
        $mail->SetFrom('info@somedomain.com', 'Bilafon');
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $mail->AddAddress($email_id, $user_name);
        return $mail->Send();
```

Its sending email from the localhost but not from the live server. On live server it shows this error:

```
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate
```

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your gmail settings. It might be SMTP disabled from there.